# Custom branding on watch load screen

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch

In the uber apple watch application, I noticed they managed to put the text 'Uber' beneath the loading indicator.

[image]

How did they accomplish this?

Comment: The accepted answer is no longer true - the setting for this title is in the Watchkit App's Info.plist file.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29860422/1103584

Comment: Note that this question was asked about WatchOS1.  In WatchOS2, the custom title shows in the status bar up top.  My answer still applies and bgilham's 'answer' doesn't answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After extensively double-checking, I can confirm there isn't currently a way to add it using the SDK. I suspect the Watch displays things slightly differently in the shipping OS or they were presenting using an old version.

Comment: This is not true.  This title is controlled by a setting in the Watchkit App's Info.plist file.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29860422/1103584

Comment: Not quite. That value defines the display name for your entire app, not just the title used in the loading view.

Comment: The original question asked how a specific app (Uber) accomplished a specific task (showing a custom title on the loading screen).  Your answer does not address the question and states that it's impossible, which is untrue since Uber is doing it in a production version of their app.  While my answer may change the display name for the whole app, it still answers the question, and yours does not, so I'm not sure where the argument is - this is a question and answer site and I answered the question.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set a value in the Watchkit App's Info.plist*.

*note that the screenshot in the original question was for WatchOS1 - in WatchOS2, the title shows in the status bar at the top instead of near the loading indicator, but this answer still controls that text.

```
1.) Open the Info.plist file for your Watchkit App.
2.) Set the title for the "Bundle display name" key
```

See the image below for help, as of Xcode 6.3.1:

[image]

Alternately, you can edit the Info.plist file as source code and paste this in there:

```
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>My Cool Title</string>
```

Comment: where exactly is this "display name" field? I wasn't able to find anything like it

Comment: @prawn I attached an image to help you out.  If it helps you, please up vote so others find the answer faster =)

Comment: ah I see it now. Thanks. Though, I still can't seem to get it to work now. Any display name I specify does not show up. And every time I navigate away from that page in the settings and go back, the display name is always empty. Is there something I"m missing?

Comment: @prawn I played around a bit more and I found the right answer - see my updated answer and screenshot and upvote if it helps!

Comment: It's worth pointing out that you're not just changing the title used in the loading view, you're changing the display name for your entire app.

Comment: @bgilham that may be true, but it still answers the question.

Comment: @DiscDev, When I do that, it isn't displaying me in the centre. Instead the title is displayed in the navigation bar. see image http://i.stack.imgur.com/JEZG8.png

Comment: @moeseth this behavior was changed in Watch OS 2 and the title shows at the top instead of in the middle now.

Comment: @prawn can you change this to be the accepted answer?  You currently have selected an answer stating "this is impossible" which is not true and will mislead others looking for the same information.